# How can I list all the matcaps and studio lights via python?

Tags: python, matcaps

I'm currently working on new addon for blender 2.8 but I got stuck because I need to find a way to list all the Matcaps and Studio lights installed inside blender.

I'm using this to list all the matcaps and studioligths installed in blender:

```
import bpy

lights= bpy.context.preferences.studio_lights

list_lights=[]

list_lights.append(tuple(lights))  

print(list_lights)
```

and It works that list all the studio ligths and matcaps, but with this structure:

```
<bpy_struct, StudioLight("basic_1.exr")>, StudioLight("03_Three_Points.sl")>...
```

and I would like to have only the name and the type of the light something like this:

```
['basic_1.exr'], ['03_Three_Points.sl']...
```

Hopefully someone could bring me some help

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the string representation of a blender class instance, for example the context scene object.

```
>> str(C.scene)
'<bpy_struct, Scene("Scene")>'
```

In this case an object of type [`bpy.types.StudioLight`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.StudioLight.html?highlight=studiolights)
Of particular interest the  `name` and `type` property.

```
>>> for sl in C.preferences.studio_lights:
...     sl.name, sl.type
...     
('Default', 'STUDIO')
('basic_1.exr', 'MATCAP')
('basic_2.exr', 'MATCAP')
('basic_dark.exr', 'MATCAP')
('basic_side.exr', 'MATCAP')
```

For example to make a dictionary with the type as the key to a list of the names of all of that type:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> studio_lights = defaultdict(list)
>>> for sl in C.preferences.studio_lights:
...     studio_lights[sl.type].append(sl.name)
...
```

What types are there?

```
>>> studio_lights.keys()
dict_keys(['STUDIO', 'MATCAP', 'WORLD'])
```

All those of type `'MATCAP'`

```
>>> studio_lights['MATCAP']
['basic_1.exr', 'basic_2.exr', 'basic_dark.exr', 'basic_side.exr', 'ceramic_dark.exr', 'ceramic_lightbulb.exr', 'check_normal+y.exr', 'check_reflection.exr', 'check_rim_dark.exr', 'check_rim_light.exr', 'clay_brown.exr', 'clay_muddy.exr', 'clay_studio.exr', 'jade.exr', 'metal_anisotropic.exr', 'metal_carpaint.exr', 'metal_lead.exr', 'metal_shiny.exr', 'pearl.exr', 'resin.exr', 'skin.exr', 'toon.exr']
```

Comment: This help me a lot thank you so much!!!!