# How can I get the filepaths of all default/built-in hdris?

Tags: python, scripting, hdri

I'd like to use the default studio light hdris in a script. I was going to create a custom path based of [`bpy.app.binary_path`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.binary_path) and then I realized that the storage location varies per operating system:

- [WIN] - `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender <version>\<version>\Datafiles\Studiolights\World\`
- [OSX] - `/Applications/Blender/Contents/Resources/<version>/Datafiles/Studiolights/World/`
- [Linux] - `/opt/Blender <version>/<version>/Datafiles/Studiolights/World/`

**Q:** Is there any way to get the filepaths of all the images in the world folder without hardcoding the folder paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the filepaths via [`Preferences.studio_lights`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Preferences.html?highlight=preferences%20studio_lights#bpy.types.Preferences.studio_lights) reference. I'd suggest use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html#python-console) to figure out:

```
>>> for i in C.preferences.studio_lights:
...     print(i.path)
...
```

Output:

```
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/studio/basic.sl
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/matcap/basic_1.exr
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/matcap/basic_2.exr
...
```

To *filter the list* and only get the filepaths of the hdris, you can use the [`StudioLight.type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.StudioLight.html#bpy.types.StudioLight.type) property:

```
>>> for i in C.preferences.studio_lights:
...     if i.type=='WORLD':
...         print (i.path)
```

Output:

```
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/world/city.exr
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/world/courtyard.exr
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/<version>/datafiles/studiolights/world/forest.exr
...
```

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for convenience:

```
>>> [sl.path for sl in C.preferences.studio_lights if sl.type=='WORLD']
```

---

Related: [How can I list all the matcaps and studio lights via python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134069/how-can-i-list-all-the-matcaps-and-studio-lights-via-python)